# Delete tableview rows after an expiration date has passed

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I have asked this question before without any luck. I want to create a tableview thats cells expire after a certain amount of time has passed. I have been able to create the code from scratch that works 60% of the time however, the problem I am facing is whenever a row gets deleted, for some reason it is still being iterated over and then trying to get removed again. Refer to the code.

```
    func handleDate(timer: Timer) {


    DispatchQueue.main.async() {

        if self.posts.count < 1 {
            print("Empty")
            timer.invalidate()

        } else {

                    let calendar = Calendar.current
                    let date = Date()

                    let componentsCurrent = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date)
                    var components = DateComponents()

                    components.hour = componentsCurrent.hour
                    components.minute = componentsCurrent.minute
                    components.second = componentsCurrent.second
                    components.year = componentsCurrent.year
                    components.month = componentsCurrent.month
                    components.day = componentsCurrent.day
                    let currentTime = calendar.date(from: components)!
                    print("CurrentTime", currentTime)

                for post in self.posts {



                    let cellID = post.postID
                    let row = self.postsInFeed.index(of: cellID)

                    let endDate = TimeInterval(post.time)


                    print("CELLID", cellID)

                    if currentTime.timeIntervalSince1970 >= endDate {


                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                            timer.invalidate()

//                           self.datesInFeed.removeFirst()
                            print(post.postID)
                            print("Deleting tableview row")

                            self.postsInFeed.removeFirst()
                            self.posts.removeFirst()
                            DataService.ds.REF_FEED.child(cellID).removeValue()

                            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: row!, section: 0)] , with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
                            self.tableView.endUpdates()
                            }
                        } else {
                            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: row!, section: 0)], with: .none)


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This code handles deleting the rows that have expired but iterating through my array of data and determine which dates have passed. The problem lies in this: (-KsP_CqeC65aWFTZzvzt
Deleting tableview row
-KsP_CqeC65aWFTZzvzt
Deleting tableview row
-KsP_CqeC65aWFTZzvzt
Deleting tableview row)

As you can see and I can also confirm from looking in my database, the post is deleted but for some reason it continues to iterate over the deleted post which causes a crash. Any help would be appreciated in advance.

Comment: I dont know if it will solve your problem but you should put else part in DispatchQueue.main.async block as well

Comment: @Chris do not force unwrap (row!) . App will crash if value goes nil somehow.

Comment: From what you've shown, it looks like you are making it much more complicated than you need to... you have `self.posts` and `self.postsInFeed` and `cellID` and `.deleteRows()` and double `.removeFirst()` and `.removeValue()` and `.reloadRows()` and, and, and... **whew!!*  I would suggest: Loop through your data array... remove elements that "have expired"... call `tableView.reloadData()`.

Comment: would you run a timer or would you just check for a date?

Comment: Try describing what you want to do *without* any code. Plain language. As in: "I'm getting records from a feed. Each record has a timestamp. I want to periodically remove records older than 24 hours." Does that sound about right? Or are you trying to remove records 30-minutes after first view? Are you also periodically getting *new* records?

Answer (score 0):

Every UITableView gets count and data from somewhere(may be an array of Strings, Feeds e.t.c). Lets call that SourceArray.

You need to manipulate the SourceArray as per your desires. Remove the value from SourceArray that you need to be removed from UITableView.

Once you are done with manipulation, call [UITableView-instance].reloadData()